Finding short circuit transconductance of a differential pair with passive load (current mirror circuit as load)
From Behzad Razavi's "Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits", Chapter 5.

I wish to find the short circuit transconductance \$G_m\$ of the above circuit.
\$G_m = \frac{I_{out}}{V_{in}}\$.
I struggle to figure out what \$I_{out}\$ should be. The circuit is not symmetric, hence I can't split it from between.
I perform small signal analysis. \$V_{DD}\$ goes to zero. \$I_1\$ goes to zero. \$I_{SS}\$ goes to zero.
Thus no current flows from M4 to M2. Circuit is broken there, essentially.
Thus, the small signal current passing through M1 is \$g_{m1}*V_{in}\$, similarly small signal current through M2 is \$g_{m2}*(-V_{in})\$.
Razavi concludes that \$I_{out} = g_{m1}*V_{in}/2\$ but I can not make sense of this solution. The book does mention that M1 and M2 become "symmetric", and I agree, however the inputs to the two MOSFETs is not the same, Its +\$V_{in}\$ for M1 while -\$V_{in}\$ for M2. I feel I'm close the answer.

Neglecting CLM (since for \$I_{out}\$ the output is grounded anyway) the current division depends only on the \$\Delta V_{GS}\$. Thus, as far as the input differential pair goes, the circuit (hence the current division) is symmetric.
If you have a hard time convincing yourself of that, split the source into two voltage sources and use superposition: \$V_{in}^{+}\$ sees a common-drain input and then a common-gate buffer to the output. \$V_{in}^{-}\$ sees a degenerated common-source path to the output.
Edit: Given the symmetry of the circuit, let's elaborate on the solution a little. Since the input voltage appears differentially across the input pair, node P appears as a virtual ground: its voltage does not change with the input voltage. This is because as the input pushes one side higher, it pulls the other side lower. Thus, node P "averages" out these variations and does not swing up or down. Next, we can break the input voltage into \$V_{in} = V_{in}/2 - (-V_{in}/2)\$, assuming that the left side of the circuit "sees" the positive potential without loss of generality. This rather trivial expression lets us use the well-known odd-mode analysis:
$$I_1 = g_{m_1}V_{in}/2,\,I_2 = -g_{m_2}V_{in}/2,\,I_{out} = I_2 = -g_{m_2}V_{in}/2.$$
Here, we assume that the positive current convention is flowing into the drain terminals of the NMOS devices. From a transient perspective, positive input voltage steers the tail current to the left, eventually starving \$M_4\$ and yielding \$I_{out} = -I_1\$. Negative inputs, on the other hand, steer the tail current to the right, eventually yielding \$I_{out} = I_{SS}-I_1\$.

I understand the symmetry but, I’m unable to figure out the currents. I’ve only worked with currents for large signal analysis before. I’m unsure why the current in M2 is not $-g_{m2}V_{in}$ Could you please elaborate?

@McSuperbX1 I modified my answer to elaborate further on the problem. Does this address your question?

Thank you for elaborating, I figured I misinterpreted the the input voltage $V_{in}$. For some reason I kept thinking that M1 gets $V_{in}$ while M2 gets $-V_{in}$! Your solution makes perfect sense, many thanks.
